# django how to add to my model a field list of its own model?

Tags: python, sql, django, models

I am making a model, where will represent  a product
but I want to add a field with complementary_products, that I want to make it a list of product.

for example,

```
id: 1 

product: dr pepper

complementary_products [chips, hotdogs]

id: 2

product: laptop

complementary_products" [mouse, usb_cable]

id: 3

product: chips

complementary_products [dr pepper, hotdogs]
```

I was trying many to many, but when I start adding prodcuts in the admin page, keeps appending, if I add 3 items,  the last one will have all the first ones =(

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complementary_products = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

if I use ForeingKey, I can only set to just one item =(

```
complementary_products = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
```

any recommendation on how can achieve this? thanks guys

[image]

when I try to add the third product, the field already have the 2 previews one
I do get the + sign button to keep adding more products, but I dont have a button to delete,  is because might be something wrong with admin form of Django?

Comment: I think M2M is better here. It will work fine, won't they?

Comment: You have to add `ProductModel` instance initially anyway..... In other words, you can't add `complementary_products` for very first instance you are creating

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you need many to many with a though table. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) does a good job at explaining it so I will not go into it here.

## Example

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CompProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductsBelong')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductsBelong(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comp = models.ForeignKey(CompProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateField()
```

Comment: found out that I can just related_name argument and Django in the back create the table,  and if I want to do custom table  I can do like you mention using the through and specify the class I want to use =), I just needed to control click on the models in the UI that I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    complementary_products = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)  # , related_name="products")
```

if set related_name= argument you can tell Django the name of the table to create behind doors.   plus I wasn't Control+clicking on the complementary_products list